# .NET Core API - Why is file attribute in nested model receives null?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, postman, postdata

I have a nested model. When I make a post request with Postman I can get all attributes except the nested `File` attribute. Why do only nested file attribute comes null and what is the solution?
The nested model and screenshots of the request are below:

```cs
public class RequestDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
    public TestModel Test { get; set; }
}

public class TestModel
{
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Square-brackets are for binding to string-keyed Dictionaries or `List<T>` members of form classes - so a `name=""` like `Test[file]` would be if you had a `Dictionary<String,IFormFile>` member in `RequestDTO`. Instead use `Test.File`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Test.file` instead of `Test[file]`.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:7212/weatherforecast' \
--form 'id="1212"' \
--form 'name="qweqweqw"' \
--form 'image=@"/<Folder-path>/sun-flower-transparent-background-additional-png-file-greeting-cards-holiday-wishes-sun-flower-transparent-129371261.jpg"' \
--form 'Test[desc]="csdds"' \
--form 'Test.file=@"/<Folder-path>/Fruit-PNG.png"'
```

> Demo

[image]